A troublesome boundary term in an integration-by-parts ... how to see it vanishes?
I'm re-wording a previous question that I had tried to simplify but inadvertently made more confusing. Here are the facts. $M$ is a 4-dimensional volume. I have a routine integration by parts:
$$\int_M v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)_{,\nu} \, d^4 x
= \int_M [v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)]_{,\nu} \, d^4 x
- \int_M v_{\mu,\nu} (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu) \, d^4 x$$
(Notation: $A_{\,,\nu} = \partial A / \partial x^\nu$. I'm also using the Einstein summation convention.)
Note an important fact. On the boundary $\partial M$:
$$(p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)_{,\nu}=0.$$
(If you wonder why this divergence vanishes on a boundary, it's because this is actually a variation $\delta p^\mu = (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)_{,\nu}$. The variation of an action integral over $M$ is being calculated and $p^\mu$ is one of the dynamical variables, which is kept constant on the boundary. Hence, the variation $\delta p^\mu=0$ on the boundary.)
I need to show the boundary term vanishes:
$$\int_M  [v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)]_{,\nu} \, d^4 x
= \int_{\partial M}  v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu) \, dS_\nu = 0 \quad (\text{SHOW!})$$
where $dS_\nu$ is the oriented hypersurface element in 3D space.
If $v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)$ were constant on the boundary, the result would be trivial. But this is not the case!
One can also write this integral
$$\int_M  [v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)]_{,\nu} \, d^4 x
= \int_{\partial M}  v_\mu n_\nu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu) \, \sqrt{|h|} \, d^3 y$$
where $n_\nu$ is the "oriented unit normal vector" on $\partial M$. (Here I am supposing that the boundary $\partial M$ can be parameterized by $x^\nu = x^\nu (y^m)$, $m=1,2,3$ and $h$ is the determinant of the matrix $h_{mn}=g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^m}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^n}$ ... but this is just linear algebra / change of variable stuff, and isn't important to the problem at hand.)
The key fact that I have to work with is that, to repeat, on the boundary $\partial M$:
$$(p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)_{,\nu}=0.$$
This is what was confusing in my previous post. Here is a divergence-free term on the boundary $\partial M$, not within $M$.

The rigorous proof besides the deviation along the lines of euclidean geometry using orthonormal bases is either using the Clifford algebra as Maxwell did unknowingly or use exterior calculus.
In the latter you start with
$$\int _M \sum _{\mu,\nu }\left (\partial_\nu \left (v_ {\mu } \left (b^{\mu } p^{\nu } - b^{\nu } p^{\mu } \right)\right) \ \mathbf dx^\nu \right)\wedge \ldots \wedge \mathbf dx^{\text {mod}(\nu+ 4, 4)}$$
$$\int _M \sum _\mu \mathbf d \left (\left (v_ {\mu } \left (b^{\mu } p^{\nu } - b^{\nu } p^{\mu } \right)\right)  \right)\wedge \mathbf dx^{\text{mod}(\nu  +1,4)}\wedge \ldots \wedge \mathbf dx^{\text {mod}(\nu + 4, 4)}$$
$$\int _M  \mathbf d\  \left ( \mathbf b(\mathbf v) \ \mathbf p  - \mathbf p(\mathbf v) \mathbf b  \right)\wedge \mathbf dx^{\text{mod}(\nu +1,4)}\wedge \ldots \wedge \mathbf dx^{\text {mod}(\nu + 4, 4)}$$
The boldface characters denote the complete forms or vectors in any basis. The volume elements can be rotated freely, only the correspondence of the exteriror derivatives with the partial derivatives of the volume $\partial_\nu M$ has to be made waterproof. But in the basis-free notation, as in the Clifford algebra method, one can always assume a regular rectangular n-cuboid to make surface expressions trivial.
$$\int _{\partial_\nu M}  \left ( \mathbf b(\mathbf v) \ \mathbf p  - \mathbf p(\mathbf v) \mathbf b \right)\wedge \mathbf dx^{\text{mod}( \nu +1,4)}\wedge \ldots \wedge \mathbf dx^{\text {mod}(\nu + 4, 4)}$$
I will not go further, because the TeX copy from my writing in Mathematica produces unreadable TeX output with every "\right" or "\nu" replaced by a "\r ight" or "\n u" by the internal conflicts of MMA and Windows text processing escapes.

Too long for a comment.
Set
$$
\boldsymbol{\omega}=(-1)^{\nu+1}\,\underbrace{v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)}_{(*)}\, dx^1\wedge \dots\wedge  \widehat{dx^\nu}\wedge\dots \wedge dx^4
$$
with summation convention and the usual convention that the factor carrying the $\widehat{\quad}$ is omitted.
Then,
$$
d\boldsymbol{\omega}=\big[v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)\big]_{,\nu}\, dx^1\wedge \dots\wedge  dx^\nu\wedge \dots \wedge dx^4
$$
which is the integrand in the first integral on your RHS. By Stokes' theorem,
$$
\int_M [v_\mu (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)]_{,\nu} \, d^4 x=\int_Md\omega =\int_{\partial M}\omega
$$
but we cannot conclude anything from that. It is quite obvious what has to vanish on $\partial M$ (namely (*)) and this is not what you assumed.

It would be enough that $(*)$ is constant on the boundary, it does not need to vanish. But that’s not the case.
